# drawing a selection rectangle on a picture box C#

Tags: c#

I have to display a picture (in my case a picture of some cars), and have to select the cars appearing in the current frame with a rectangle, I want to enable selecting a rectangle around a car, enable deleting a rectangle, if possible moving it to the sides also.

I tried to use Graphics on my pictureBox, but I don't know how to clear a rectangle when I have custom background (the picture itself, and not a solid color).

I asked for a headlines and not a full code (but if there is so, I would like to get), I am new with C# here is what I managed to write, this only draws  at the end of the selection and doesn't reflect anything while doing the selection itself:

```
    private void prevPictureBox_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        Point startPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y); //
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            currRect = new Rectangle();                                          
            currRect.X = startPoint.X;
            currRect.Y = startPoint.Y;
            isDrag = true;
        }
    }

    private void prevPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (isDrag) {
            endPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            currRect.Width = endPoint.X - startPoint.X;
            currRect.Height = endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y;
        }
    }

    private void prevPictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDrag = false;
        graphics = this.prevPictureBox.CreateGraphics();
        graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red), currRect.X, currRect.Y, currRect.Width, currRect.Height);
    }
```

Comment: This would be a better question (both easier to answer and less likely to be closed) if you showed us the code you've already written and tried for this. You're asking us to do quite a lot of work for you here. You're basically re-writing a basic image-editing program like Microsoft Paint, the source code for which probably wouldn't fit in a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Are you using WPF? can you put your snippet here?

Comment: You should do paintings in `Paint()` event and use `e.Graphics` to use the advantage of double buffered surface of your `PictureBox` or `Form`, and to get a neat presentation otherwise you're going to face some issues with drawing consistency. You better take look at `Invalidate()` method too.